# React-native: tvOS networking library with cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, networking, react-native

I'm looking for a networking library compatible with react-native. With this library I want to have local cache.

I really want to do that with the good way and a good architecture too.
With my Model, Stores, APIService inside my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the following lib called [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).
I didn't use it yet, but there are a lot of recommendations out there for.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, this library is compatible with tvOS ?

Comment: Welcomed, I don't know for sure as I didn't use it, but I think that it is more than a generic JS lib.I have read some recommendation on its usage with react native.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: @StackyUser Welocmed :)